# Angular4 Retrigger a subscription after a ViewChild is rendered again

Tags: angular

I have the following code in my `component` :

```
@ViewChild('form') form: NgForm
isFormShown = true

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.form.valueChanges
        .subscribe(() => {
            console.log("form has changed")
        })
  }
```

and in my template :

```
<button type="button" (click)="isFormShown = !isFormShown">CLICK</button>
<form #form="ngForm" *ngIf="isFormShown">
   ...
</form>
```

if I click on my button twice, (so my form will disappear and reappear). It doesn't seem like my subscription is still existing. Indeed, I am fiddling with my form's inputs, and I have nothing logged.
What do I need to do to make it work again ?

Comment: Your first subscription is valid because the form is visible. When you click the button however, it disappears. You should create a method that you call in (click) event and put the subscribe logic there.

Comment: Do you also want to clear the form values when it reappears or is it okay to have values that user might have filled in before he clicked the btn to hide the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of `*ngIf="isFormShown"` ,

`ngIf` simlpy remove the component if `false` and add it again if its `true`

**You should use:**

```
[hidden]="!isFormShown"
```

> For only show hide purpose always use hidden

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay to have existing values remain in the form than you can simply **hide** it instead of using `ngIf` :

```
<button type="button" (click)="isFormShown = !isFormShown">CLICK</button>
<form #form="ngForm" [hidden]="!isFormShown">
...
</form>
```

But if you want to clear all existing values, than you need to unsubscribe and subscribe again on view toggle of your form like below:

html:

```
<button type="button" (click)="toggleForm()">CLICK</button>
<form #form="ngForm" *ngIf="isFormShown">
...
</form>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;
public isFormShown: boolean = true;
private formChangeSubscriber: any;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.formChangeSubscriber = this.form.valueChanges
    .subscribe(() => {
        console.log("form has changed")
    })
}

toggleForm(): void {
    this.formChangeSubscriber.unsubscribe();
    this.isFormShown = !this.isFormShown;
    if(this.isFormShown) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // wait for a tick so angular can render the changes 
            this.formChangeSubscriber = this.form.valueChanges
            .subscribe(() => {
                console.log("form has changed");
            });
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

You can also view the [plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/oUrncsKi9iL6LFZmpO2J?p=preview) of above code.